# How to connect custom domain and Azure domain

Tags: azure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkLr9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTMBE.png)I just have moved my custom domain curtirsuacidade.com.br to Azure and now I want to connect it to my app Curtir, that is running on Azure (curtir.azurewebsites.net). My Azure plan is S1 level. I am using the Custom Domain tool from Azure, but the button Add Custom Domain is hidden. What am I forgetting? I do not have any SSL certificates associate with my app yet.

Comment: Share a screenshot of your web app screen if possible where you can't locate the "Add custom domain" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do NOT need SSL certificates to associate with a custom domain. And S1 (anything B1 or above) service plan is more than enough. Where are you looking for the custom domain tab? it should be there in your **web app** resource that runs on your app service plan
[image]

How does yours look?
For the Azure docs on binding a domain to your web app see here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings

Comment: Tanks for your replay. In this view, I can see only the Azure domain (curtir.azurewebsites.net). And when I click + Add Custom Domain, even after I add my own domain and  get positive evoluation, the button Add Custom Domain remains hidden. My Azure account is new and I think that there is some restrictions yet.

Comment: Pretty sure it has got nothing to do with your azure account being new. can you show me a screenshot of your "Add custom domain blade"? Are all the validations passing for your domain name? Do you see any errors for Hostname availability or domain ownership when you validate your domain? You should find these errors at the bottom of your blade if any.

Comment: Tank you again Rimaz. I just edited my question above including the screenshot. In the bottom of the right side, you can see de button "Adicionar domínio personalizado" hidden. And in the bottom of the left side a message "Este tipo de assinatura não é elegível para adquirir domínio", that means my account cannot get domain.

Comment: I added one more screenshot. If you need more details, please ask me.

Comment: You are right. My DNS configuration was wrong. Now erevything is working perfectly. Thank you very much again.

Comment: That's awesome!